# Как при помощи цикла посмотреть всю базу данных и вытащить отдельные столбики?

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite3

Суть такая, мне нужно каким-то образом проверить всю базу данных и вытащить из неё все id'шники записей где например имя равно Максим а записать эти данные в переменную, подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать

Comment: Лучше определиться с таблицей и столбцом с этими записями. Если таблица неизвестная или таких может быть много, то это другая задача

Comment: Потрудитесь, пожалуйста, сначала ознакомиться с языком SQL и работой с БД в python, попробуйте сделать это сами, а уже потом возвращайтесь с конкретными вопросами

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стоит сказать что set() выбирает элементы рандомно, так что если задача стоит ещё и выстроить всё id`шники по порядку нужно использовать: result.sorted()

```
with sq.connect("database.db") as con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        names = list(set(cur.execute("select id from table where name = 'Максим'").fetchall()))
        result= [x[0] for x in names]
        print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor.execute('SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = "Максим"')

ids = cursor.fetchone()
```

еще можно

```
ids = [i[0] for i in ids]
```